# Memory Leak when running PYMC3 in a FOR LOOP

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, memory-leaks, theano, pymc3

I'm using PYMC3 to fit tennis players' serve ace rates using Bayesian fitting to a Beta curve. Each time the code loops through a player, the memory use increases a little. I'm trying to do this for 400+ players over 3 different surfaces and I run out of memory after about 200 players. I don't understand why the memory doesn't get re-set after each loop iteration as I don't think I'm using info from prior loop iterations. 
I think the issue may be to do with the Trace. I saw advice somewhere that I should not have trace = pm.sample(...) but rather just pm.sample(...) and then grab that data after the program has run. I'm not sure how to implement that fix and I'm hoping there's a more straightforward solution out there to what I imagine would be a fairly common problem (though I haven't seen questions on it much online).

The relevant bits of the code are shown below. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import pymc3 as pm
prior_parameters = beta.fit(chart_data, floc = 0, fscale = 1)
prior_a, prior_b = prior_parameters[0:2]
for i in range(server_by_surface_pct.shape[0]):
    #srv_count is number of serves taken by player i on surface j
    srv_count = pivot_srv_count.iat[i, j]  
    #Go to next iteration of loop if no serves for player i on surface j
    if np.isnan(srv_count):
        continue
    #ace_pct is the percent of serves from player i on surface j that are aces
    ace_pct = server_by_surface_pct.iat[i,j]
    #calculate ace_count (number of aces) by player i on surface j
    ace_count = round(srv_count*ace_pct,0)
    #zero aces is possible so replace NANs with ZERO
    if np.isnan(ace_count):
        ace_count = 0.0
    #pm = PYMC3 -- this is the Bayesian fitting model
    with pm.Model() as model:
        theta_prior = pm.Beta('prior', prior_a, prior_b)
        observations = pm.Binomial('obs',n = srv_count, p = theta_prior, observed = ace_count)
        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)
        trace = pm.sample(1000, step=step, start=start, progressbar=True)      
    #mean of the trace is the new fitted serve percent for player i on surface j
    server_by_surface_pct_fitted.iat[i,j] = np.mean(trace['prior'])
```

Comment: I am digging on recreating that memory leak, but wanted to mention that for this model, `np.mean(trace['prior']) = prior_a / (prior_b + prior_a + srv_count)`, which does not require MCMC sampling at all.

Comment: Thanks for digging on this for me colcarroll. But since prior_a and prior_ b are parameters to the beta distribution which is being used as the prior distribution, I don't think the formula holds. I could be wrong. Say the ave ace rate is about 7%. When a player goes through the loop with a 3% ace rate with 50 serves counted, his mean trace value will be something like 4%. But a player with 3% ace rate and 100 serves counted would only get mean trace of say 3.5%.  prior_a and prior_b should be constant per surface.